# getting stale element reference exception while trying to extract src attribute of nested iframes

Tags: java, selenium

i am trying to get src attributes of all nested iframes but i am getting stale reference exception.Here is the code

```
public class findAllSources {

    ArrayList<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Test
    public void iframeTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chrome driver");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.engadget.com/");
        List<WebElement> allFrames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]"));
        for (WebElement frame : allFrames) {
            if(frame.isDisplayed()){
                    System.out.println("We clicked frame "+frame);
                    System.out.println(" with a source  "+frame.getAttribute("src"));
                    sources.add(frame.getAttribute("src"));
                    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
                    findDeeperFrames(driver); 
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            }
        }
    }

    public void findDeeperFrames(ChromeDriver driver){

        List<WebElement> deeperFrames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]"));
        for (WebElement nframe: deeperFrames) {
            if (nframe.isDisplayed()){

                if (!nframe.getAttribute("src").isEmpty()){
                sources.add(nframe.getAttribute("src"));
                System.out.println("Nested source "+ nframe.getAttribute("src"));}

                 driver.switchTo().frame(nframe);
                 findDeeperFrames(driver);
                 //getting out of the frame
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other approach by which i can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same `StaleElementReferenceException` when I tried to interact with an iframe (stored as a WebElement variable), that was actually still visible on the page, so I had no idea what caused the issue. The reason was that first, I stored the iframe as a variable, after that, I switched to that frame using `driver.switchTo().frame(thatFrame);` (to interact with elements inside the frame), but I never switched back to the original, main frame with `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`, before I wanted to interact with the frame itself again. And "from inside" the frame, the actual frame DOM element is a stale object (not attached to the inner frame's DOM).

<sub>*Maybe not an exact answer to your problem, just a note for those who search for this exception and frames.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

Your code is returning StaleExcceptionError, because after using  `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` your code gets into next Iteration of `for` LOOP which is still using `allFrames` webElement list which  was stored initially before switching to new frame and Those elements are not attached to DOM anymore. So in order to avoid that you have to Identify that frame  s list once again as shown below:

```
 List<WebElement> deeperFrames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]"));


 for (int j=1; j<=deeperFrames.size(); j++) {


            List<WebElement> myFrames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));

            WebElement nframe = myFrames.get(j-1);


            if (nframe.isDisplayed())
            {
                 if (!nframe.getAttribute("src").isEmpty()){
            sources.add(nframe.getAttribute("src"));
            System.out.println("Nested source "+ nframe.getAttribute("src"));}

             driver.switchTo().frame(nframe);
             findDeeperFrames(driver);
             //getting out of the frame
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

            }
}
```

Comment: Stale Exception is when you try switch to another frame orwindow and then after switching back to original window; you try to use webelements which were stored previously  before switching, which line throws you that error?

Comment: i get on   if (nframe.isDisplayed()) {}